# Jersey/JAX-RS ExceptionMappers and Inheritance

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey/JAX-RS to implement a RESTful web service. I have a question about the [`ExceptionMapper` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html), which doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.

Say I have the following custom (extend `RuntimeException`) exceptions:

- `FizzException extends RuntimeException`
- `BuzzException extends FizzException`

Now let's say that I want my exception mappers to perform the following `Exception`-to-`Response` mappings:

- `FizzException` actually maps to an HTTP 404 NOT FOUND
- `BuzzException` maps to an HTTP 403 UNAUTHORIZED
- Everything else maps to an HTTP 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

So, if I understand the API correctly, I need to implement 3 different exception mappers:

```
@Provider
public class DefaultExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    Response toResponse(Exception exc) {
        // Map to HTTP 500
    }
}

@Provider
public class FizzExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<FizzException> {
    @Override
    Response toResponse(Exception exc) {
        // Map to HTTP 404
    }
}

@Provider
public class BuzzExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BuzzException> {
    @Override
    Response toResponse(Exception exc) {
        // Map to HTTP 403
    }
}
```

However, this has me curious: since we have exception class inheritance going on, which mappers will actually fire? For instance:

- `BuzzException` extends `FizzException`, which ultimately extends `Exception`. So, if a `BuzzException` is thrown, which mapper will fire: `BuzzExceptionMapper`, `FizzExceptionMapper` or `DefaultExceptionMapper`?
- The other way around: when an `Exception` is thrown, since a `BuzzException` is, ultimately, an `Exception`, which mapper fires: `BuzzExceptionMapper`, `FizzExceptionMapper` or `DefaultExceptionMapper`?

Comment: A cow is an animal. So if you take a cow but call it "an animal" and then throw it from a mountain, what are you throwing off of the mountain? Its still a cow in the end. Similarly, if you throw a BuzzException then that is what you are throwing off of the mountain - even if you call it a FizzException.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby I kind of see your analogy but could still see a situation where a `BuzzExceptionMapp` considers a `BuzzException` to be an `Exception`, and therefore maps thrown `Exception`s, which was the basis of my question. But it seems like Jersey is smart enough to do the necessary class checking, so no worries :-)

Comment: _"So, if I understand the API correctly, I need to implement 3 different exception mappers"_ - You don't _have_ to :-) In your `FizzExceptionMapper`, you could check `if (e.getClass() == BuzzException.class)`. Also just an FYI, it's also pretty common to make your exception classes extends `WebApplicationException` and just map the response in the constructors, as seen [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e435). The default Jersey mapper will handle it. We don't need to create our own. Unless this exception class already exists, then you _would_ need the mapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Most specific exception mapper** will be called.

So in your case :

- `BuzzException` will be mapped by `BuzzExceptionMapper`
- `FizzException` will be mapped by `FizzExceptionMapper`
- others `Exception` will be mapped by `DefaultExceptionMapper`